# запятая в цитате

Tags: пунктуация, цитата

В приведенном предложении, по правилам, перед «совершался» необходима запятая, однако предложение, заключенное в кавычки, является цитатой, продолжающей авторский текст. Существуют ли правила оформления запятой в цитате? – В древней Греции существовал «обычай буфоний («убиение быка»)(,) совершался в честь Зевса по окончании молотьбы» [….]. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Цитаты обычно помогают дать речевую характеристику герою или указывают на оригинальность чьей-то мысли, здесь же нет ни того, ни другого, обычные сведения, которые можно почерпнуть из любого учебника или справочника. Не вижу смысла использовать здесь  цитату, можно всё это сказать от своего лица и сослаться на источник сведений с помощью сносок, вводных слов или предложений или оформить как прямую речь.

1.В древней Греции существовал обычай буфоний (убиение быка), который  совершался в честь Зевса по окончании молотьбы    (И.А. Лисовый, К.А. Ревяко. Античный мир в терминах, именах и названиях: Словарь-справочник по истории и культуре Древней Греции и Рима / Науч. ред. А.И. Немировский. - 3-е изд. - Мн: Беларусь, 2001) https://antiquites.academic.ru/750

2.Как говорят учёные-историки,в древней Греции существовал обычай буфоний (убиение быка), который  совершался в честь Зевса по окончании молотьбы.

3.Справочная литература утверждает:"В древней Греции существовал обычай буфоний (убиение быка), который  совершался в честь Зевса по окончании молотьбы".

Answer (score 0):

Постановка цитаты безграмотная - уникальный случай. Цитата - это отдельная конструкция. А здесь `В древней Греции существовал обычай буфоний` - это явно простое предложение, которое нельзя "ломать" цитатой. Лучше начать цитату с начала предложения.

Можно также легко исправить двоеточием:

В древней Греции существовало: «обычай буфоний (убиение быка) - совершался в честь Зевса по окончании молотьбы» [….]

`убиение быка` - кавычки не нужны, так как тут нет переносного смысла. Лучше всего поставить тире. Запятую тоже можно. А можно и ничего не ставить - но это хуже.
После или до цитаты должно быть разъяснение о авторе, иначе читателю не понятна причина наличия кавычек.